# Read output of multiple write in QProcess one by one

Tags: qt, qprocess

Can anyone help me read the output of qprocess after write and loop until all task is done?
I have this code

```
  wifi->write("scan\n");  
  wifi->closeWriteChannel();
  wifi->waitForBytesWritten(100);
  wifi->waitForReadyRead(100);
  wifi->waitForFinished(100);
  qDebug() << "read output" << wifi->readAllStandardOutput();
  wifi->write("scan\n");  
  wifi->closeWriteChannel();
  wifi->waitForBytesWritten(100);
  wifi->waitForReadyRead(100);
  wifi->waitForFinished(100);
  qDebug() << "read output" << wifi->readAllStandardOutput();
```

the expected output must be

"OK"

"scan results"

but the ouput is

"OK"

""

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your multiple waits are not useful for anything. All you care about is when the process finishes, so have a single `waitForFinished` call with a much longer timeout (those scans don't happen in ~100ms, a few seconds is a good minimum).

You should not be using the blocking `waitForXxx` methods. They trip up everyone and are a source of unending grief. Forget that they exist. Use process's signals to react to events as they happen.

### Qt 5 + C++11

This is the way forward. This is why you should insist on using a modern development environment, if you can. It's less typing and easier to understand.

```
void MyObject::startWifi() {
  auto process = new QProcess(this);
  process->start("program", QStringList() << "argument");
  connect(process, &QProcess::started, [process]{
    process->write("scan\n");
    process->closeWriteChannel();
  });
  connect(process, &QProcess::finished, [process]{
    qDebug() << process->readAllStandardOutput();
    process->deleteLater();
  });
}
```

### Qt 4

```
class MyObject : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QProcess m_wifi;
  Q_SLOT void onStarted() {
    m_wifi.write("scan\n");
    m_wifi.closeWriteChannel();
  }
  Q_SLOT void onFinished() {
    qDebug() << m_wifi.readAllStandardOutput();
  }
public:
  MyObject(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
    connect(&m_wifi, SIGNAL(started()), SLOT(onStarted()));
    connect(&m_wifi, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)),
                     SLOT(onFinished()));
  }
  Q_SLOT void start() {
    m_wifi.start("program", QStringList() << "argument");
  }
};
```

Then invoke the `start` method/slot on an instance of this object. That's all.

Comment: my problem is that the 2nd time i used 
wifi->readAllStandardOutput(); after wifi->write("command"); the output is ""